# ArcGIS print service not showing images or text in layout template?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing

Steps using ArcGIS 10.2:

1. with arcmap create a simple map. Edit it to include an image and a text.
2. save said map in the templates folder
3. close arcmap. reopen and create a new blank map using the template created in previous steps. The new map correctly inherits text and image.
4. create print service
5. when consumed, via js api, only the map, not the image or the text, shows.